# Will confiscation of over-the-limit alcohol prevent someone travelling to Cuba?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, cuba

I'm traveling to Cuba with family members. All arrangements were made when I found out that one person in group had alcohol 2 bottles rum confiscated there less than six months ago as it was not declared and wasn't duty free. Will this person even be allowed to enter the country? What will happen to him? While the rest of us are having fun and trying not to worry what happens if he gets stopped from entering?

Comment: Where did this confiscation happen? And when? Was there a criminal charge?

Comment: >2 bottles rum confiscated ... as it was not declared That's called "smuggling". And I believe Cuba (and pretty much everywhere else) doesn't appreciate it very much. Was your relative charged with anything? Fined? Or just told not to do it again? If the latter, they should be ok. Cuba wants your money and probably won't let minor mistakes get in the way. Don't bring any booze this time though. (and why would you bring rum TO Cuba anyway?)

Comment: If he was allowed entry earlier and was not charged then that chapter is over. It does not seem logical if they allowed entry even when they caught him last time and they would stop now because of the incident earlier even though there was an entry made after the bottles were caught.